# Contradiction in rotational EMF

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits

The formula for motional EMF is

$$\oint{({\bf{v}}\times{\bf{B}})\cdot d{\bf{l}}}=-\frac{d}{dt}\int{{\bf{B}}\cdot {\bf{\hat{n}}}da}$$

However applying this for a rotating disk of radius a there seems to be a sign contradiction

$${\bf{v}}\times{\bf{B}}=\omega s{\bf{\hat{\varphi}}}\times B{\bf{\hat{z}}}=B\omega s {\bf{\hat{s}}}$$

$$\int^{a}_{0}B\omega sds=\frac{1}{2}B\omega a^2$$

Now doing it with the Double Integral by moving the derivative inside

$$-\frac{d}{dt}\int^{2\pi}_{0}\int^{a}_{0}Bsdsd\varphi=-\int^{a}_{0}B\omega sds=-\frac{1}{2}B\omega a^2$$

These expressions are similar but have the opposite sign why is this.

My question is why is there this contradiction here did I do something wrong like these formulas should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a disk rotating about its axis, then ${\vec{ dl}}\times{\vec v}=0$.
Also, since $\partial_t{\vec B}=\omega\times\vec B$, ${\hat n}\cdot\partial_t{\vec B}=0.$

Comment: Griffiths uses s instead of ρ for the radial coordinate in Cylindrical Coordinates. Also the magnetic field isn’t time varying the objects position is.

Comment: I had gotten confused about the variables in your question. Now each side equals zero.

Comment: You got the formula wrong its (vxB)•dl NOT (dlxv) you just have the wrong formulas

Comment: $({\vec v}\times{\vec  B})\cdot {\vec {dl}}=( {\vec {dl}}\times{\vec v })\cdot {\vec B}$